# Dockerfile: Inherit environmental variables from shell

Tags: docker, environment-variables, dockerfile

When building an image using a `Dockerfile`, in order to make some env vars available to the docker build context, one should explicitly declare associations of the form

```
ENV MYVAR=MYVALUE
```

AFAIK (correct me if I am misguided here), the environmental variables exported to the shell from which the `docker build` command is executed, are **not** passed to the Docker build context, i.e. if in my shell I have previously

```
export FOO=BAR
```

having the following declaration in my `Dockerfile`

```
ENV FOO=$FOO
```

and then echoing (still from within the `Dockerfile`) `$FOO` will print an empty string.

So if all of the above is correct, my question is if there is a way for the docker build context to inherit the environment of the shell being called from.

Answer (score 6):

You could define default values with `ARG`:

```
ARG build_var=default_value
ENV ENV_VAR=$build_var
```

and then override at build time:

```
docker build --build-arg build_var=$HOST_VAR
```

Answer (score -2):

You can get the value from your terminal and pass it like this...

```
$ export test="works"
$ docker run --name your_image_name -e TEST="${test}" -d -P your_image
$ docker exec -it your_image_name /bin/bash
$ env
...
TEST=works
```